# Can red-black tree contain nodes with the same key?

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, treemap, multimap

I'm trying to implement a simple red-black tree. Node of the tree contains fields for key:int and value:string. I have not seen examples with same keys stored in the tree.
But there is multimap class in C++ or TreeMap in Java that utilizes red-black tree and it can store two ore more same keys.
So, is red-black tree stores only unique keys? Is there any strict rule about this or universal definition?
P.S.:Imho, as red-black tree is a binary search tree, so it cannot store duplicate keys because a binary search tree stores only unique values by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [BST definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

> key in each node must be greater than or equal to any key stored in the left subtree, and less than or equal to any key stored in the right subtree

Thus, BST allows duplicate keys.

If you take a look of for instance [insert operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree#Insertion), there is a line which decides  whether to insert to the left (key is less) or to the right (key is greater or equal). Thus, there is no problem to insert duplicate keys.

When one traverses a tree for a key, it can easily find all values for the given key.

Comment: Thank you! So in my implementation of red-black tree i need to find a way to properly insert and store nodes with the same keys?

Comment: Go with the same insertion logic to the left/right subtree, just choose which one should keep the equal keys. Once a leaf is found, the key will be inserted, together with fixing red-black properties.